# Incosistency in Django multiple databases

Tags: mysql, django, multiple-databases, django-database

I have set up Django multiple-database configs. I have one default database for writing and two slave databases for reading. I'm using mySql.

Using Django shell, I write to the database and using the sql shell I can make sure the write operation was successful on the default and the slaves.

However, when I try to query the database from the shell I can't find the latest added value. Am I missing something ?

Comment: I added a new object to the database ... something like
obj = Obj(params)
obj.save()
I tried to get all the objects ... Obj.objects.all() ... and the queryset can't see that the latest object was added to the DB ... however, I'm sure it was added to the database as I connected to the sql shell and got the table's elements ... and the last object was setting right there :)

Comment: you should try to access the slave database as below
    Obj.using("slave_db_name").all()
For clear idea view this link, [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327808/django-multiple-databases/24361766#24361766